# C++23 Dangling Reference Compilation Error

Tags: c++, reference, c++23

The following apparently results in a compilation error in C++23:

```
int& f(int& x) {
    int y = ++x;
    return y;
}
```

[error](https://godbolt.org/z/qYarbf9ze): `cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int&' to an rvalue of type 'int'`

But this [one](https://godbolt.org/z/575ov4rrx) doesn't seem to even give us a warning:

```
int& f(int x) {
    int &y = ++x;
    return y;
}
```

Is this so much more difficult to catch during the compilation phase?

Thanks.

Comment: GCC gives a warning, but only when optimization is enabled strangely enough: https://godbolt.org/z/EnPaGMqT9

Comment: Implicit move in return (the rule for which is updated in C++23) never applies to variables declared as lvalue references.

Comment: What is obvious for us, is not simple for a compiler. Here `y` reference the return of an operator returning a reference, then what is referenced by `y` is returned. In fact `y` reference the local `x` it's an issue. If we assume that the type of `x` were a class, nothing says that `++x` reference `x`.

Comment: @user12002570 I'm talking about the second version of the function.  Only MSVC [gives a warning](https://godbolt.org/z/dxPvddj9E) for that version.

Comment: @user12002570 I think he mean's compiler's analysis on `int& y=++x;`

Comment: @user12002570, in your example, `y` is no more a reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Why the first example doesn't compile, unlike the second

To understand the difference, one must understand why the code fails to compile in C++23.
Namely, in the first example, `y` is [move-eligible](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#def:move-eligible) because it names an [implicitly movable entity](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#def:entity,implicitly_movable) and appears in a `return` statement. Therefore:

> **The expression is an xvalue if it is move-eligible** (see below); an lvalue if the entity is a function, variable [...]

- [[expr.prim.id.unqual] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#1)

> An *[implicitly movable entity](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#def:entity,implicitly_movable)* is a variable of automatic storage duration that is either a **non-volatile object** or an rvalue reference to a non-volatile object type.

- [[expr.prim.id.unqual] p4](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#4)

In the first example, the move-eligibility of `y` makes it an rvalue, and the returned reference cannot bind to it.
In the second example, `y` does not name an implicitly movable entity, so it's considered to be an lvalue, and the reference binding succeeds.

The fact that the first example doesn't compile is *not* because the C++ committee has made an effort to detect dangling references; instead, this is just a convenient side effect of some wording changes when it comes to implicit moves in `return` statements.

### Detecting dangling references in general

Detecting dangling references outside of this one, trivial case is very difficult. It generally requires lifetime annotations for functions, similar to Rust.
Some proposals are focused on detecting simple cases at least.

For example, Herb Sutter has proposed standardizing analysis based on acyclic control flow graphs (ACFGs) in [P1179: Lifetime safety: Preventing common dangling](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1179r1.pdf). This would at least make local analysis (within the same function) possible. The fact that this proposal is 47 pages long demonstrates that it's not a trivial issue though.

More trivial cases can be caught with [@BrianBi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481267/brian-bi)'s proposal [P2748: Disallow Binding a Returned Glvalue to a Temporary](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2748r2.html)

Comment: How about P2255?

Comment: @WeijunZhou from what I can tell [P2255: A type trait to detect reference binding to temporary](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2255r2.html) can only detect when a reference binds to a temporary object, not when it binds to an object that is local to the current function and would dangle when the function returns. It could be helpful in eliminating some further trivial cases.

Comment: Fair enough. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this so much more difficult to catch during the compilation phase?

The important thing to understand here is that C++ does not have a rule like "you shall not have a dangling reference" for the compiler to enforce. Instead, there are a bunch of more specific language rules that, when added up, catch some instances that would lead to dangling.

Specifically, in this example:

```cpp
int& f(int& x) {
    int y = ++x;
    return y;
}
```

We now have a rule that says that `return y;` should treat `y` as an rvalue because it's a local variable (see [Jan Schultke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77671359/2069064) for the specific rule and terminology), and you can't bind an rvalue to `int&`, so this doesn't compile. That's great, because had it compiled (like it used to), that would be  a dangling reference.

However, in this example:

```cpp
int& f(int x) {
    int &y = ++x;
    return y;
}
```

There just isn't a simple(~ish) rule to reject this function. `y` is already a reference, so returning it is fine. Binding the result of `++x` to a reference is also fine. This is only wrong for a more complicated lifetime analysis - that `++x` is an lvalue with the same lifetime of `x`, so returning `y` would exceed the lifetime of `x`. But there's no specific C++ rule here. You'd need to run a static analyzer to catch This.

Which, [clang-analyzer does](https://godbolt.org/z/WroG51M1n) (but not clang or gcc with any warning that I can find):

```
<source>:3:5: warning: Address of stack memory associated with local variable 'x' returned to caller [clang-analyzer-core.StackAddressEscape]
    1 | int& f(int x) {
      |        ~~~~~
    2 |     int &y = ++x;
    3 |     return y;
      |     ^      ~
<source>:3:5: note: Address of stack memory associated with local variable 'x' returned to caller
    1 | int& f(int x) {
      |        ~~~~~
    2 |     int &y = ++x;
    3 |     return y;
      |     ^      ~
```

Similarly there was experimental work on more lifetime tracking (`-Wlifetime`) that [caught this](https://godbolt.org/z/qxEzffsfn), although the warning you got was "returning a dangling pointer" which is maybe not the best text.

Otherwise - C++ isn't Rust in this sense. There just isn't such a "you shall not dangle" rule (which makes even more complicated examples involving containers and views and iterators much harder to properly diagnose). But given that we have an easy rule which rejects one dangling reference but no such easy rule for the other, I guess this is an existence proof that indeed one is much more difficult to catch than the other.